# Simple Javascript throws "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ~"

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

In code behind i have

```
  Public arrayString As String() = {"100~USA~UsaDescr", "101~SPAIN~SpainDescr"}
```

The javascript which throws the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ~` is the following.

```
   $(document).ready(function () {

            var Country = eval('[<% =String.Join(", ", arrayString)%>]');

            $('#slider').slider({
                max: 1,
                min: 0,
                slide: function (event, ui) {
                    var splitValues = Country[ui.value].split("~");
                    $('#hpGame').html(splitValues[0]);
                    $('#hpHome').html(splitValues[1]);
                    $('#hpAway').html(splitValues[2]);
                }
            });
        });
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Check your rendered javascript. I think you're losing the quotes around the strings.

Comment: remove the eval and just store the string, then inspect that string. likely it isn't what you expect it to be.

Comment: I would also recommend using a javascript serializer, like [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) or [JSON.net](http://james.newtonking.com/json) instead of trying to reinvent that wheel.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should change this

```
var Country = eval('[<% =String.Join(", ", arrayString)%>]');
```

by this

```
var Country = ['<% =String.Join("', '", arrayString)%>'];
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest fix involving the smallest change would be to just add quotes to your string from the VB side:

```
Public arrayString As String() = {"""100~USA~UsaDescr""", """101~SPAIN~SpainDescr"""}
```

As someone mentioned in a comment, you also shouldn't need the `eval`.

Here's what's happening. Let's say you just had a variable called `str` containing the string `"foo"`. Then this:

```
<%= str %>
```

would give you:

```
foo
```

Meanwhile, let's say you wrapped `str` in quotes:

```
str = """" + str + """"
```

Then you would get:

```
"foo"
```

Since JavaScript needs those quotes, they need to be part of the string. I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is caused as follows :

when you try to join this

```
{"100~USA~UsaDescr", "101~SPAIN~SpainDescr"}
```

the result will be

```
"100~USA~UsaDescr, 101~SPAIN~SpainDescr"
```

so if you try to do

```
eval("100~USA~UsaDescr, 101~SPAIN~SpainDescr")
```

it will cause an error because the tilde has a special meaning  :

> The tilde is an operator that does something that you’d normally think
>   wouldn’t have any purpose. It is a unary operator that takes the
>   expression to its right performs this small algorithm on it (where N
>   is the expression to the right of the tilde): -(N+1).

sourse : http://www.joezimjs.com/javascript/great-mystery-of-the-tilde/

hence when you eval it it will cause the error

Answer (score 0):

You're losing the quotes wrapping the strings, and you don't (and shouldn't ever) need to use `eval()`. Also, javascript serialization is a common problem, you shouldn't need to (and just shouldn't) try to do that manually:

In your code-behind:

```
Dim serializer as New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()
Public arrayString As String() = {"100~USA~UsaDescr", "101~SPAIN~SpainDescr"}
Dim arrayJson as String = serializer.Serialize(arrayString)
```

In your page:

```
var Country = <%=arrayJson%>;
```

Comment: Better than wikipedia! Did not know that! But i get a syntax error next to <%=arrayJson%>; and the script does not seem to work. I f i remove the eval part, it works great

Comment: A VB syntax error, or javascript? What does the rendered javascript look like?

Comment: @Chocol8 So what does the rendered javascript look like, and what is the error?